# Django : How to pass context?

Tags: django, django-templates

I know about passing the context to templates, but I am bit confused with the given scenario, please help

class X:

```
id:

name:

status:
```

Class Main:

```
number1: object of X

number2: object of X

message: "Hello World!"
```

I get Object of Main which has two X objects but with different contexts.
I want to write one template for X and pass different conetext to it for code re usability and maintainability.

so I am trying to do this in my presentation logic, where I have object of Main

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="tab-results">
    {% include "render/objectX.html" %}
  </div>
```

and `objectX.html` is:

```
{% block content %}
<div id="d">
 <table id="c">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>id : {{ x.id }}</td>
     <td>name : {{ x.name }}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

how can I pass the Main.number1(object of X) explicitly to template??

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way would be to wrap the include with a `{% with %}` template tag.  For example, assuming you have `main` in your context:

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="tab-results">
    {% with main.number1 as x %}
        {% include "render/objectX.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
</div>
```

This will put the `number1` object into the context as variable named `x`, which can be used in the included template.

Answer (score 2):

or you can use it like this

```
{% include "render/objectX.html" with x=main.number1  %}
```

according to django documention https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include